# Is it possible to store an in-memory Jena Dataset as a triple-store?

Tags: dataset, sparql, rdf, jena, triplestore

Warning! This question is a catch, I bring 0 XP considering RDF systems, so I couldn't express this in a single question. Feel free to skip the first two paragraphs.

**What I'm trying to build, overall**
I'm currently building a Spring app that will be the back-end for a system that will gather measurements.
I want to store the info in a triple-store instead of an RDBMS.
So, you may imagine a Spring Boot app with the addition of the Jena library.

**The workflow of the system**
About the methodology that I'm planning to deploy.
1. Once the App is up and running it would either create or connect to an existing triple-store database.
2. A POST request reaches an app controller.
3. I use SPARQL query to insert the new entry to the triple-store.
4. Other Controller/Service/DAO methods exist to serve GET requests for SELECT queries on the triple-store.

*The only reason I provided such a detailed view of my final goal is to avoid answers that would call my question a XY-problem.

**The actual problem**
1. Does a `org.apache.jena.query.Dataset` represent an in memory triple-store or is this kind of Dataset a completely different data structure?
2. If a Dataset is indeed a triple-store, then how can I store this in-memory Dataset to retrieve it in a later session?
3. If indeed one can store a Dataset, then what are the options? Is the default storing a Dataset as a file with `.tdb` extension? If so then what is the method for that and under which class?
4. If so far I am correct in my guess then would the `assemble` method be sufficient to "retrieve" the triple-store from the file stored?
5. Do all triple-store databases follow this concept, of being stored in .tdb files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.apache.jena.query.Dataset` is an interface - there are multiple implementations with different characteristics.

`DatasetFactory` makes datasets of various kinds. `DatasetFactory.createTxnMem` is an in-memory, transactional dataset. It can be initialized with the contents of files but updates do not change the files.

An in-memory only exists for the JVM-session.

If you want data and data changes  to persist across sessions, you can use TDB for persistent storage. Try `TDBFactory` or `TDB2Factory`

TDB (TDB1 or TDB2) are triplestore databases.

---

`Fuseki` is the triple store server. You can send SPARQL requests to Fuseki (query, update, bulk upload, ...)

You can start Fuseki with a TDB database (it creates if it does not exist)

`fuseki-server -tdb2 --loc DB /myData`

".tdb" isn't a file extension Apache Jena uses.  Databases are a directory of files.